# Full screen flags not working on fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

I happen to have a single activity project and I want one fragment to have fullscreen features. This fragment is opened from a deferent scenario, bur currently this code that I added is not working, I also  noticed this is deprecated. What are the  best way to handle this case. Here is how it looks, I want to hide the `appbar`, and the icon and the `bottom bar` too.

Here is an image[image]

```
 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    requireActivity().window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()

    requireActivity().window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 window.apply {
        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        } else {
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        }
        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
```